# Multi level collapsable/accordion that goes on infinitely without breaking table content

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a multi-level accordion with tables inside it that can have any number of levels.
[this is my requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7MrB.jpg)

I'm still a noob so I've tried some other stuff on code pen which had unlimited nesting but the CDN or something seems to break my layout but I finally found
one that works and now my layout looks like [this(base level)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FspPG.jpg) [(expanded)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJ5zm.jpg) but the table gets broken. 
My current Code is a mess so id like to know if there is a clean way to do it, current full code:
https://pastebin.com/PBTDhxyY

Accordion Code(base level):

```
<div class="row product-listing">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body nested-accordion">
            <div class="row mt-10">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="panel-group" id="level1-accordion">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#level1-accordion" href="#plast-pro-1" class="collapsed">
                                    <table class="table">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>LEVEL 1</td>
                                            <?php 
                                                for ($k = 0 ; $k < 11; $k++){ 
                                                    echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>'; 
                                                }
                                                ?>
                                            <td>0.00</td>
                                            <td>0.00</td>
                                            <td>0.00</td>
                                            <td>0.00</td>
                                            <td>0.00</td>
                                            <td>0.00</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div id="plast-pro-1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="panel-group" id="level2-accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                                                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#level2-accordion" href="#plast-pro-2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="plast-pro-2">
                                                                <table class="table">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td>LEVEL 2</td>
                                                                        <?php 
                                                                            for ($k = 0 ; $k < 11; $k++){ 
                                                                                echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>'; 
                                                                            }
                                                                            ?>
                                                                        <td>0.00</td>
                                                                        <td>0.00</td>
                                                                        <td>0.00</td>
                                                                        <td>0.00</td>
                                                                        <td>0.00</td>
                                                                        <td>0.00</td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </a>
                                                        </h4>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="panel-group" id="level2test" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                                                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#level2test" href="#level2testlink" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="plast-pro-2">
                                                                <table class="table">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td>LEVEL 2</td>
                                                                        <?php 
                                                                            for ($k = 0 ; $k < 11; $k++){ 
                                                                                echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>'; 
                                                                            }
                                                                            ?>
                                                                        <td>0.00</td>
                                                                        <td>0.00</td>
                                                                        <td>0.00</td>
                                                                        <td>0.00</td>
                                                                        <td>0.00</td>
                                                                        <td>0.00</td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </a>
                                                        </h4>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="panel-group" id="level2testb" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                                                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#level2testb" href="#level2testlinkb" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="plast-pro-2">
                                                                <table class="table">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td>LEVEL 2</td>
                                                                        <?php 
                                                                            for ($k = 0 ; $k < 11; $k++){ 
                                                                                echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>'; 
                                                                            }
                                                                            ?>
                                                                        <td>0.00</td>
                                                                        <td>0.00</td>
                                                                        <td>0.00</td>
                                                                        <td>0.00</td>
                                                                        <td>0.00</td>
                                                                        <td>0.00</td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </a>
                                                        </h4>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _“but the table gets broken”_ - you don’t have a _“the”_ table here, you have _many_ individual, independent tables. And of course they each individually size based on their content - because they have no connection to each other. You either need to specify the column widths you want - or not rip this apart into multiple tables in the first place. (Then you can’t use default BS accordion functionality, but will have to implement something similar based on showing/hiding table rows yourself.)